# Why is stack driver unable to find the test results for my uptime check

Tags: uptime

I just setup an uptime check on StackDriver. Next to the check, however, I have a series of black circles. When I hover over each of them I receive the message

`Unable to find check results.`

I setup the check 10 minutes ago, and configured it to check every 5 minutes. So I figure it should have results by now. Additionally, hitting `Test` on the editing panel of each of the uptime checks returns the expected results (either a 404 or a 200 status).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just had to be patient, and it took a while for the results to sync. For any other folks like me out there, I'll leave this on the internet.